# Perl, how to print the package name?

Tags: perl, package

Is it possible - in Perl - to access the name of the current package (for example, to print it in a customized error report) ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [perldoc perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html):

```
The special symbol __PACKAGE__ contains the current package,
but cannot (easily) be used to construct variable names.
```

Comment: Why it cannot (easily) be used to construct variable names?

Comment: it has no sigil and doesn't get interpolated. You'd need something like `my $var = __PACKAGE__ .'::MySubClass';` which can get fiddly in more complex cases. (Compare with `my $var = "${pkg}::MySubClass";`

Answer (score 11):

`__PACKAGE__` will get you the package in which the code was compiled.

Alternatively, you might want [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html). It gets the package of the code that called the current sub.

```
package Report;

sub gen_report {
   my $report = "This report is generated for ".caller().".\n";  # MyModule
   ...
}

package MyModule;

Report::gen_report();
```